# How do I solve "ValueError: axes don't match array" when using xarray.apply_ufunc?

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I am getting an error using xarray.apply_ufunc() to my dataset. The function works fine by itself, but it throws an error when called from apply_ufunc().

The script is below:

```
def drought_index(water_deficit):
    # Ensure all inputs are Dask arrays
    water_deficit = da.from_array(water_deficit)
    water_deficit[water_deficit > 0] = 0
    water_deficit = da.abs(water_deficit)
    print(len(water_deficit))

    # Generate a list of thresholds
    max_thres = 37
    thresholds = da.arange(0, max_thres, 0.01)
    print(len(thresholds))

    # For each threshold, calculate the number of water deficits equal to or below the threshold
    counts, _ = da.histogram(water_deficit, bins=thresholds)

    # Calculate the cumulative sum of the counts
    cumulative_counts = da.cumsum(counts)

    # Calculate the integral using the trapezoidal rule
    integral = 0.5 * da.sum(
        (cumulative_counts[1:] + cumulative_counts[:-1])
        * (thresholds[1:-1] - thresholds[:-2])
    )
    print(len(integral))

    # Calculate the maximum possible integral (no-stress situation)
    max_integral = len(water_deficit) * (max_thres)

    # Calculate the percentage of stress
    stress_percentage = ((max_integral - integral) / max_integral) * 100
    print(len(stress_percentage))

    return stress_percentage.compute()


# Read the netCDF files using Dask
years = range(2004, 2019)
precip_files = ['SAMERICA_PP{}.nc'.format(year) for year in years]
evapotranspiration_files = ['SAMERICA_ET{}.nc'.format(year) for year in years]
lateral_flow_files = ['SAMERICA_QSLAT{}.nc'.format(year) for year in years]

precip_data = xr.open_mfdataset(precip_files)
evapotranspiration_data = xr.open_mfdataset(evapotranspiration_files)
lateral_flow_data = xr.open_mfdataset(lateral_flow_files)

# Test the calc_dei function on a 100 x 100 subset of the data
subset_precip = precip_data['PP'][:, 5000:5100, 5000:5100].chunk({'month': -1})
subset_evapotranspiration = evapotranspiration_data['ET'][:, 5000:5100, 5000:5100].chunk({'month': -1})
subset_lateral_flow = lateral_flow_data['QSLAT'][:, 5000:5100, 5000:5100].chunk({'month': -1})
subset_lateral_flow = xr.where(subset_lateral_flow < 0, 0, subset_lateral_flow)

# Calculate water deficit
wd = (subset_precip + subset_lateral_flow) - subset_evapotranspiration

# Apply the test function along the time dimension
result = xr.apply_ufunc(drought_index, wd,
                        input_core_dims=[['month']],
                        dask='parallelized',
                        output_dtypes=[wd.dtype])

# Print the resulting Xarray DataArray
print(result)
```

When I run the script above, I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[129], line 1
----> 1 res = result[1,1].compute()

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py:1089, in DataArray.compute(self, **kwargs)
   1070 """Manually trigger loading of this array's data from disk or a
   1071 remote source into memory and return a new array. The original is
   1072 left unaltered.
   (...)
   1086 dask.compute
   1087 """
   1088 new = self.copy(deep=False)
-> 1089 return new.load(**kwargs)

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xarray/core/dataarray.py:1063, in DataArray.load(self, **kwargs)
   1045 def load(self: T_DataArray, **kwargs) -> T_DataArray:
   1046     """Manually trigger loading of this array's data from disk or a
   1047     remote source into memory and return this array.
   1048 
   (...)
   1061     dask.compute
   1062     """
-> 1063     ds = self._to_temp_dataset().load(**kwargs)
   1064     new = self._from_temp_dataset(ds)
   1065     self._variable = new._variable

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/xarray/core/dataset.py:746, in Dataset.load(self, **kwargs)
    743 import dask.array as da
    745 # evaluate all the dask arrays simultaneously
--> 746 evaluated_data = da.compute(*lazy_data.values(), **kwargs)
    748 for k, data in zip(lazy_data, evaluated_data):
    749     self.variables[k].data = data

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/base.py:599, in compute(traverse, optimize_graph, scheduler, get, *args, **kwargs)
    596     keys.append(x.__dask_keys__())
    597     postcomputes.append(x.__dask_postcompute__())
--> 599 results = schedule(dsk, keys, **kwargs)
    600 return repack([f(r, *a) for r, (f, a) in zip(results, postcomputes)])

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/threaded.py:89, in get(dsk, keys, cache, num_workers, pool, **kwargs)
     86     elif isinstance(pool, multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
     87         pool = MultiprocessingPoolExecutor(pool)
---> 89 results = get_async(
     90     pool.submit,
     91     pool._max_workers,
     92     dsk,
     93     keys,
     94     cache=cache,
     95     get_id=_thread_get_id,
     96     pack_exception=pack_exception,
     97     **kwargs,
     98 )
    100 # Cleanup pools associated to dead threads
    101 with pools_lock:

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/local.py:511, in get_async(submit, num_workers, dsk, result, cache, get_id, rerun_exceptions_locally, pack_exception, raise_exception, callbacks, dumps, loads, chunksize, **kwargs)
    509         _execute_task(task, data)  # Re-execute locally
    510     else:
--> 511         raise_exception(exc, tb)
    512 res, worker_id = loads(res_info)
    513 state["cache"][key] = res

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/local.py:319, in reraise(exc, tb)
    317 if exc.__traceback__ is not tb:
    318     raise exc.with_traceback(tb)
--> 319 raise exc

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/local.py:224, in execute_task(key, task_info, dumps, loads, get_id, pack_exception)
    222 try:
    223     task, data = loads(task_info)
--> 224     result = _execute_task(task, data)
    225     id = get_id()
    226     result = dumps((result, id))

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/core.py:119, in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    115     func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
    116     # Note: Don't assign the subtask results to a variable. numpy detects
    117     # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    118     # operations in-place.
--> 119     return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    120 elif not ishashable(arg):
    121     return arg

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/core.py:119, in <genexpr>(.0)
    115     func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
    116     # Note: Don't assign the subtask results to a variable. numpy detects
    117     # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    118     # operations in-place.
--> 119     return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    120 elif not ishashable(arg):
    121     return arg

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/core.py:119, in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    115     func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
    116     # Note: Don't assign the subtask results to a variable. numpy detects
    117     # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    118     # operations in-place.
--> 119     return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    120 elif not ishashable(arg):
    121     return arg

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/optimization.py:990, in SubgraphCallable.__call__(self, *args)
    988 if not len(args) == len(self.inkeys):
    989     raise ValueError("Expected %d args, got %d" % (len(self.inkeys), len(args)))
--> 990 return core.get(self.dsk, self.outkey, dict(zip(self.inkeys, args)))

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/core.py:149, in get(dsk, out, cache)
    147 for key in toposort(dsk):
    148     task = dsk[key]
--> 149     result = _execute_task(task, cache)
    150     cache[key] = result
    151 result = _execute_task(out, cache)

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/core.py:119, in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    115     func, args = arg[0], arg[1:]
    116     # Note: Don't assign the subtask results to a variable. numpy detects
    117     # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    118     # operations in-place.
--> 119     return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    120 elif not ishashable(arg):
    121     return arg

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/utils.py:73, in apply(func, args, kwargs)
     42 """Apply a function given its positional and keyword arguments.
     43 
     44 Equivalent to ``func(*args, **kwargs)``
   (...)
     70 >>> dsk = {'task-name': task}  # adds the task to a low level Dask task graph
     71 """
     72 if kwargs:
---> 73     return func(*args, **kwargs)
     74 else:
     75     return func(*args)

File <__array_function__ internals>:200, in transpose(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/array/core.py:1760, in Array.__array_function__(self, func, types, args, kwargs)
   1757 if has_keyword(da_func, "like"):
   1758     kwargs["like"] = self
-> 1760 return da_func(*args, **kwargs)

File ~/mambaforge/envs/caio23/lib/python3.11/site-packages/dask/array/routines.py:180, in transpose(a, axes)
    178 if axes:
    179     if len(axes) != a.ndim:
--> 180         raise ValueError("axes don't match array")
    181     axes = tuple(d + a.ndim if d < 0 else d for d in axes)
    182 else:

ValueError: axes don't match array
```

However, when I call the function separately using the wd array from the script, it works perfectly:

```
drought_index(subset_precip[:,1,1].values,
                       subset_evapotranspiration[:,1,1].values,
                       subset_lateral_flow[:,1,1].values)

Output: 2.5768018018017846
```